# Capture two USB webcams at high frame rate

Tags: webcam, framerate

Does anyone know of any software that will allow me to capture two USB webcams simultaneously, but with a high frame rate (24-30 fps)?

I have tried various CCTV software, including Blue Iris and Multi Webcam Recorder but only managed to get 17 fps - I can get 30 fps with one camera.

For my needs I really do need reasonable frame rates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you USB cameras provide high resolution and high framerates, I suggest you to use 2 different USB controllers, one for each cam. A single USB controller may not provide enough bandwidth.